# Why do people use "Lady Wife" to refer to their wife?

Tags: expressions

I was listening to a play on the radio this afternoon and one of the characters was told to go home to their **lady wife**. I've heard the term on numerous occasions, and until I started reading this forum I had never given it much thought.

But now it strikes me as an odd expression, as there is no such thing as a gentleman wife, or a lady husband. So why do people use it?

Comment: What was the play, and when was it written? When was it set? A play might have been written during a particular time (or set in a particular time) - and the language in the script would reflect that. The term *lady wife* may have been common in a bygone era, but please remember this: you may hear a character say something in a play, but that doesn't mean that the language is still in use. Perhaps this expression was common at one time, but I don't believe you'll see it much in contemporary use.

Comment: @J.R. I've certainly heard it in contemporary use, more often British television than local to me, but locally too. (I understand that Australian slang has *GLW* for "good lady wife", but I've no idea how current or common that is there).

Comment: The play was the afternoon play on R4 (in Great Britain), which was certainly contemporary, if not memorable. However, the phrase is certainly in use today.

Comment: @JonHanna & Facebook: Thanks for those enlightening comments. I'd venture to say that, to my U.S. ears at least, the phrase sounds quaintly dated. I guess we just don't use it over here so much.

Comment: @J.R. oh, I'd say both earnest and ironic uses on this side of the pond are quaintly dated too; most often used self-consciously as such.

Comment: Somebody on another forum summed it up when they said that the kind of person who would sit in a pub and use **lady wife** without irony would also be most likely to call the landlord "mine host", and should be avoided at all cost.

Comment: It may be use in Baluchi term of politeness for wife I think so

Comment: Not a term in wide use in the U.S., must be a British Commonwealth English thing, which makes sense because American English early on made an effort to purge itself of aristocratic distinctions, sometimes by making everyone a noble (as in the use of "Sir" to refer to any adult man) and sometimes denying it to all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Lady* is used as the female equivalent of several different male titles, is part of some other female titles, along with being used as a "polite" term for *woman* (polite in "scare quotes" because it can be found objectionable in some circumstances, which would be an essay's worth of discussion in itself). It originally meant the mistress of a household; a sense which is mostly obsolete but not entirely extinct.

"My lady" can also be used as a form of address (though is mostly obsolete in non-ironic use).

As such there's a bewildering variety of ways in which a given person (especially if a man) addressing a given woman may or may not be using the term, depending on when in history it was, her social station, his relative social station, and his relationship to her.

And then there's a bunch more from ironic uses, or as pet names in some dialects (some dialects even have *duchess* as a way one might address one's wife, or perhaps even a woman generally).

"Lady wife" survives that confusing mess as a term half ironic and half straight, with tone perhaps leaning it heavily into the ironic ("oh oh! must not stay out drinking any later, the lady wife will not approve!") or more heavily into the straight ("my good lady wife is a joy and a rock of support to me").

About the closest you'd have for a woman to use of her husband is a very definitely ironic* use of "lord and master". Normally so ironic that it would more likely be used if she was speaking critical of him, than fondly.

*Barring some specialised tastes, so to speak.

Comment: If your wife refers to you as **Lord and Master** in a non-humorous fashion then you know you are in trouble!

Comment: On the contrary, there's all sorts of fun possible down that road. As said though, a specialised taste.